# return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); is not calling the parent method

Tags: java, android, methods, return, super

I have the  return `super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);` in my  `public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {}` I was wondering would there be any reason why the parent method is not beeing called. I don't know if you need any more context let me know.

Comment: did you add this line ```setHasOptionsMenu(true)```  in ```onCreate``` ?

Comment: yes added on my activity bu did not achieve anything

Comment: Can you post an [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

You could be returning true (as occurs in many examples of custom options menu selection handling) before reaching the `super.onOptionsItemSelected` call.

Tough to answer without seeing your `onOptionsItemSelected` method and your `onCreate` method